# Javascript nested object traversal

Tags: javascript, object

I'm doing a code where I have to traverse a nested object and return all the values in a single string. For example, if this is the input:

```
var obj = {
name: "root",
contents: [
  {
    name: "A",
    contents: [
      {
        name: "fileA1",
        contents: ["Hello!"]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    name: "B",
    contents: [
      {
        name: "dirB1",
        contents: [
          {
            name: "fileB1.1",
            contents: ["Hello!"]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
};
```

The output should be:

```
root
A
fileA1
Hello!
B
dirB1
fileB1.1
Hello!
```

My code is:

```
function toArray(obj) {
var result = '';
for (const prop in obj) {
    const value = obj[prop];
    if (typeof value === 'object') {
        result+=(toArray(value)); 
    }
    else {
        result+=(value);
    }
}
//console.log(result);
return result;
}
```

But when I run it, it returns the following string:

```
Hello!
fileA1undefined
undefined
Aundefined
Hello!
fileB1.1undefined
undefined
dirB1undefined
undefined
Bundefined
undefinedundefined
rootundefined
```

Why am I getting the "undefined" with the values and how can I fix this?

Comment: for..in with array is a bad idea may be check for that?.I have seen somewhere that using for in for array results in unpredictables values like undefined.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [`flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) and [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) like this:

```js
var obj = {name:"root",contents:[{name:"A",contents:[{name:"fileA1",contents:["Hello!"]}]},{name:"B",contents:[{name:"dirB1",contents:[{name:"fileB1.1",contents:["Hello!"]}]}]}]}

const getValues = o =>
  Object.values(o).flatMap(v => typeof(v) === 'object' ? getValues(v) : v)

console.log(getValues(obj).join('\n'))
```

If you add a `\n` to `result += value`, your code returns the desired result:

```js
function toArray(obj) {
  var result = '';
  for (const prop in obj) {
    const value = obj[prop];
    if (typeof value === 'object') {
      result += toArray(value);
    } else {
      result += value + '\n';
    }
  }
  return result;
}

var obj = {name:"root",contents:[{name:"A",contents:[{name:"fileA1",contents:["Hello!"]}]},{name:"B",contents:[{name:"dirB1",contents:[{name:"fileB1.1",contents:["Hello!"]}]}]}]}

console.log(toArray(obj))
```

Answer (score 0):

Running your code I get the output of

> "rootAfileA1Hello!BdirB1fileB1.1Hello!"

so it is not reproducible in my browsers, however, your object has some additional members with the value of undefined. So, let's add newline and avoid undefined values:

```
var obj = {
name: "root",
contents: [
  {
    name: "A",
    contents: [
      {
        name: "fileA1",
        contents: ["Hello!"]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    name: "B",
    contents: [
      {
        name: "dirB1",
        contents: [
          {
            name: "fileB1.1",
            contents: ["Hello!"]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
};
function toArray(obj) {
var result = '';
for (const prop in obj) {
    const value = obj[prop];
    if (typeof value === 'object') {
        result+=(toArray(value)); 
    }
    else if (value !== undefined) {
        result+=(value) + "\n";
    }
}
//console.log(result);
return result;
}
toArray(obj);
```